# how to get/trigger the last anchor in a list item

Tags: jquery, html, dom

source:

```
<li>
<p>html html html <a>
<p>html html
<a>
</li>
```

I have list item with some paragraphs and after the last paragraph there is always a link. The idea is to trigger the last  anchor

('a:last') doesn't work

code:

```
$(somelink).on('click', this, function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      loadArticlePage($(this));
  });

function loadArticlePage(thisObj){
  setTimeout(function(){
    thisObj.closest('li').find('a:last')[0].click();
},1500);
}
```

the case now it is still triggering the first anchow in the dom
closest method is used to find the right part of the html.
html is rendered when I click on the 'somelink'

```
example
<li>
<somelink>
<dataholder>
</li>
```

the dataholder will be filled with data (see top)  when you click on the somelink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('ul li > a:last').trigger('click');
```

Here `li > a` is just targeting those anchors which are children of `li` not grand-children which are available in the `p`.

---

a small test is here:

```js
$('li > a:last').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
  <p><a href='#'>grand-child of li and child of "p"</a></p>
  <a href='#'>child of li</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Updates:

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(){
     $(this).find('> a:last').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: And how will you combine this with my closest call

Comment: why do you want to combine it with closest? Is there any need for closest?

Comment: I fixed it with some class name.
your solution was fine thanks.